# Inverse fourier transform of a function which is a fundamental solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x)=(1+|x|^2)^{-1}$.

I need to calculate $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)$.

I've proven that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and I know that the fourier transform is an isometry of $\mathcal{S}'$ where $L^2$ is happily embedded.

I tried using the direct formula of the inverse transform but that is an insance calculation.

I suspect I am supposed to use the fact that $\mathcal{F}^{-1}f$ is a fundamental solution to $I-\Delta$ but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance, Shai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do this almost straightforwardly. Define
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\mathbf{k})=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-i(k_x x+k_yy+k_zz)}}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz
\end{align}
Now rotate the coordinate system in $x,y,z$-space so that the direction of $\mathbf{k}=(k_x,k_y,k_z)$ coincides with $z$-direction in new coordinates. Then, passing to spherical coordinates, we get
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\mathbf{k})&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-ikr\cos\theta}}{1+r^2}r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta d\varphi=\\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{-ikr\cos\theta}}{1+r^2}r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta=\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi^2k}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin kr}{1+r^2}rdr=\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi^2k}\cdot\frac{\pi\sinh k}{2}=\\
&=-\frac{\sinh k}{4\pi k}.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Here $k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}$. It is easy to check that (1) solves $(-\Delta_k+1)\hat{f}=0$ for $k\ne0$, as you expected.